# How do I design a C# visual motif that looks like visual studio error list

Tags: c#, user-interface

How do I design a C# visual motif that looks like visual studio error list?

--I have a program that examines the user provided inputs, and I would like to send errors back to the user in a format similar to the "error list" display in Visual Studio 2005.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ListView with the view propterty set to  "Details" possibly.